# Unable to get update GreenRobot EventBus subscription inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, greenrobot-eventbus

Inside my activity am posting the GreenRobot Event .
Inside fragment i register like

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

But unable to automatically fired the subscription side fragment.
is it possible to get updated inside fragment if yes 
any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: I made my comment as an answer to prevent others trying to answer an already answered question.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `EventBus.getDefault().register(this);` on `onStart()`

and

Calling `EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);` on `onDestory()` of your `fragment`,

*is enough to `register` and `unregister` **listenening to events***